# Use powershell to set primary display in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, display, multiple-monitors, powershell

I have a windows 10 laptop in the work office connected to a dell display. I have a remote desktop connection and ssh access.

Currently, the primary display is the laptop screen. Is there a way to change the primary display to the dell monitor?

Or change the display setting to mirroring.

`DisplaySwitch.exe` does not do anything. No error message either.

```
PS> Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root\WMI" -Class "WMIMonitorID"

__GENUS                : 2
__CLASS                : WmiMonitorID
__SUPERCLASS           : MSMonitorClass
__DYNASTY              : MSMonitorClass
__RELPATH              : WmiMonitorID.InstanceName="DISPLAY\\BOE06F9\\4&15a49d7&0&UID265988_0"
__PROPERTY_COUNT       : 9
__DERIVATION           : {MSMonitorClass}
__SERVER               : DESKTOP-VFR2B3O
__NAMESPACE            : root\WMI
__PATH                 : \\DESKTOP-VFR2B3O\root\WMI:WmiMonitorID.InstanceName="DISPLAY\\BOE06F9\\4&15a49d7&0&UID265988_0"
Active                 : True
# this is the laptop screen, I want to use display 2
InstanceName           : DISPLAY\BOE06F9\4&15a49d7&0&UID265988_0
ManufacturerName       : {66, 79, 69, 0...}
ProductCodeID          : {48, 54, 70, 57...}
SerialNumberID         : {48, 0, 0, 0...}
UserFriendlyName       :
UserFriendlyNameLength : 0
WeekOfManufacture      : 38
YearOfManufacture      : 2016
PSComputerName         : DESKTOP-VFR2B3O
```

```
PS> Get-WmiObject win32_desktopmonitor


DeviceID            : DesktopMonitor1
DisplayType         :
MonitorManufacturer :
Name                : Default Monitor
ScreenHeight        :
ScreenWidth         :

DeviceID            : DesktopMonitor2
DisplayType         :
MonitorManufacturer : (Standard monitor types)
Name                : Generic PnP Monitor
ScreenHeight        : 1080
ScreenWidth         : 1920
```